# checking one servlet status from another servlet

Tags: java, servlets

My application consists of 2 servlets,the major one loads the config files in init method and processes get/post requests,
if anything fails during config load, i need to stop the application.

as far i know, i couldnt be able to stop whole application context through some java code ,hence i'm throwing UnavailableException in Servlet.hence i wont be processing get/post request.

but the second servlet does some dynamic reload of configuration on demand.but irrespective of major servlet failed or succeed,it processes reloading requests.

can you suggest a way to check the status of major servlet (running,stopped).so that second servlet can take decision whether to accept reload request or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just share some status variable, like `AtomicBoolean` between two servlets. By the way, it's more clear design to make both servlets just accept http requests, decode them and pass requests to corresponding business-logic objects. This way, servlets will contain only logic concerned with HTTP sending/receiving.

Comment: Thanks Victor, It works , we have business logic out of servlet,servlets acts as controller, but both of these are interdependant and handling different set of requests