# Is a servlet independent from another (process wise)?

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I've create a servlet to let me know if the webapp inside a Tomcat container is running or not. But now, I'm wondering if it is possible that one servlet responds and not another one? i.e. can two independent servlets (in the same webapp) be independently responsive or can I assume if one responds the other will respond?

Something that gives some clues but not enough information.

[Useful source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609556/checking-one-servlet-status-from-another-servlet)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is a servlet independent from another (process wise)?*

Yes. The [Servlet 3.0 spec](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315) tells among others the following:

> #### 2.3.2.1 Error Conditions on Initialization
>
> During initialization, the servlet instance can throw an `UnavailableException` or a
>   `ServletException`. In this case, the servlet must not be placed into active service
>   and must be released by the servlet container. The `destroy` method is not called as it
>   is considered unsuccessful initialization.

It doesn't say any line about that the other servlets should not be initialized or something. Just that the servlet is not been placed into active service.

---

**Update** as per the comments: the same spec tells the following whenever a successfully initialized servlet throws an exception during the service:

> #### 2.3.3.2 Exceptions During Request Handling
>
> A servlet may throw either a `ServletException` or an `UnavailableException`
>   during the service of a request. A `ServletException` signals that some error
>   occurred during the processing of the request and that the container should take
>   appropriate measures to clean up the request.
>
> An `UnavailableException` signals that the servlet is unable to handle requests
>   either temporarily or permanently. If a permanent unavailability is indicated by the `UnavailableException`, the servlet container must remove the servlet from service, call its destroy method, and release the servlet instance. Any requests refused by the container by that cause must be returned with a SC_NOT_FOUND (404) response.

Comment: Thank you, but after initialization passes and all is OK, if a servlet crashes (generates an exception), hangs, or fails to respond, can I assume the whole webapp has gone down? Or if I call a different servlet while one is "broken" can the latest still repond properly? thx

Comment: Read section 2.3.3.2. The container will remove the servlet if it has thrown an `UnavailableException`. It won't do that for other exceptions like `ServletException`. The remnant will just run as specified. For the case you're too lazy to download/read the spec, I've updated the answer with the relevant extract ;)

Comment: Was just reading it! Not the one to skip a good spec reading :) Thank for the pointers.